# Python inference

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am new to python but not to programming. Is there a way to know if two object have the same functions and fields?

I have this scenario

```
var1 = func1()
var2 = func2()
func3(var1)
func3(var2)
```

Both `func1` and `func2` are functions in a library I use that have little to no documentation.

There is a high probability that `var1` and `var2` are the same type of object but how can i be sure?

Say that I know that `func3(var1)` works, is there a way i can know if it will work with `var2`?

Comment: `type(var1) == type(var2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, Python often uses [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing): if object has required properties and methods, then it can be used. You can [check](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) it this way:

```
if hasattr(var2, 'method_name'):
   ... your code ...
```

Another way of duct typing implementation is implicit. For example, if your function increments its argument, you may not check the argument but just write:

```
result = int(var1) + 1
```

And if `var1` cannot be cast to int, user will get quite a readable error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'MyCustomClass'
```

**Second**, you can explicitly [check](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) if var is an instance of some class (or its descendant). If you know that `var1` is an instance of `dict`:

```
if isinstance(var2, dict):
    ... your code ...
```

This code will work if `var2` is an instance of `dict`, `defaultdict` or other subclass of `dict`.

**Conclusion**: there is no single receipt of validating parameters. You always need to keep balance between protecting from invalid attribute values and code readability. Pretend that you are the user who call your function: will it be obvious what type should the arguments have? If you pass wrong value, will the error be understandable?

Comment: or, even more commonly imo, is EAFP style: `try: var2.method_name(); ... ; except AttributeError: # blah`

Comment: @AdamSmith I guess it's a matter of taste :) Both variants fit, but I prefer explicit check (code becomes less indented).

Comment: About duck typing, is there a way to know what functions expect?

Comment: @Imapler Updated my answer. Generally you can figure out function's expectation only by reading its code (or to leave it implicit, as I described)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to know if two object have the same functions and fields?

Technically yes, though I wouldn't recommend it. You can compare the results of `dir` called on each.

```
if dir(var1) == dir(var2):
    # both have the same attributes
```

However I still don't recommend that because of how fragile this is. If both `var1` and `var2` implement a function called `frobnicate`, but define it completely differently, `dir` will have no way of knowing they're different.

Slightly better is comparing the types:

```
if type(var1) == type(var2):
    # both are objects of the same type
```

But that doesn't do *much* to help, since having the same type doesn't ensure that they'll have the same attributes.

> Say that I know that `func3(var1)` works, is there a way i can know if it will work with `var2`

```
if var1 is var2:
    # it'll work
```

That's really it. If both `var1` and `var2` are the same object then you know it'll work identically. Any other answer relies on the definition of `func3`.

Comment: I would strongly recommend *not* to use comparison of ```dir```: it is some kind of hack. Speaking about comparing ```type``` - it will work. But if you expect ```type(a)  == ClassA```, you won't be able to pass the instance of ```ClassA```'s descendant.

Comment: And speaking about ```var1 is var2``` - it is surely correct, but I guess it is not that Imapler expects (his function is surely expected to work with different variables, not the only one).

Comment: @EugenePrimako agreed on both counts, and my answer addresses both concerns :)